Imperium of Man compared to The Culture: differences in ship architecture?
So... I have some ideas for a crossover with The Culture and Warhammer 40k banging around in my head. I know 40k very well, but I can't say the same for the Culture, and research material for specific architectural details regarding the Culture and its ships is a little... scarce. Hence the existence of this question:
What sort of visual differences exist between the interior of a typical Imperial Navy vessel and typical Culture vessel?

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I don't think there is a "typical interior" of a Culture vessel.  I don't recall if it's the Falling Outside... in Surface Detail or the Mistake not... In Hydrogen Sonata, but one of them is transporting its passenger in a hollowed-out effector blister that simulates whatever environment the passenger (Y'breq or Cossont respectively) desires.

A Culture vessel could entirely mimic a ship from the Warhammer Universe if it wanted to (or found it amusing). Whereas the Imperial Navy has a certain gritty aesthetic forced on it by the Imperium's culture, military needs and punitive attitude towards advanced AI.

There's typically a lot fewer skulls on display in a Culture ship. And no hordes of slaves loading giant shells into cannons by hand.

So Culture Ships can restructure their interior to match that of another species design to put visiting diplomats at ease... good to know (though the Imperials will probably be more creeped out by it than anything else). Thanks for the explanation.

Culture ships are the mobile housing for the Minds (incredibly advanced AIs) which control them. Cynics claim that Minds really make up the Culture, and that organic beings and lesser robots (Drones) are merely their pets. Culture Minds claim that organic beings and Drones are an important part of Culture culture and good decisionmaking. (If nothing else, organic crew prevent gung-ho warships from going kamikaze after transmitting a copy of their mind to a rear habitat.)
Inside the Culture ship, one striking thing is that there is no real crew. There are passengers. And these passengers include both not-quite-humans and outright aliens. The not-quite-humans have access to incredibly advanced bio-engineering and they can change their appearance and biochemistry at a whim.
Modern Culture ships have no defined outermost hull. There is the physical structure, wrapped in a number of force fields. Some of them are pressure-proof and passengers can go there. Where the ship ends and space starts is hard to decide.
One does not enter the engine rooms or weaponry mounts. The passengers have individual living quarters and community spaces like bars or parks. Those can be whatever the Mind wants, and usually the Minds will oblige requests from the passengers, even what seems outrageous. It would be hard to think of anything a Mind cannot do.
There is no bridge. No gunnery controls. Battles between Culture ships and equivalent enemies are over in milliseconds, often because one ship hacks the AI of another and wins that way.
